# MySQL Grouping Forums & its subForums into same group before doing greatest-n-per-group

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, categories

On a webpage, I want to show a list of Forums (parent_id = 0) 
and for each Forum, show the latest (newest) 3 topics in the group of that Forum AND its subForums

```
APPLE (Forum)
 iPad3        Apr 12   (Topic from subForum "Tablets")
 Genius Bar   Apr 11   (Topic from Forum "APPLE")
 iPodNano     Apr 10   (Topic from subForum "Portables")
repeat with next forum
```

MySQL 5.5 structure

```
table FORUMS (contains Forums and subForums, 2 level hierarchy max)
 id (autoinc)
 parent_id (0 if Forum, link to other rows id if subForum)
 name


table TOPICS (a Topic is a child of Forums or subForums)
 id (autoinc)
 forum_id (linked to FORUMS table
 name
 date_added (datetime)
```

I can get the result set for Forums from a simple query, into an array in PHP and loop thru that.

I'm stuck on how to create the second result set that would show the top 3 topics.

I've read the posts about Greatest-N-Per-Group, and have tried them, but I think my idea adds a level of complexity. My brain is mush at this point, so I'm asking for help.

Do I create a mysql variable to hold a comma separated list of id's of the Forum id and it's subForums, and then use that for the value of an IN (1, 4, 6) statement?

Or is this a bad design/idea and too expensive to execute?

I've read many related posts on SO, but any links you can point me too I will read also.

Comment: You have explained that forums have subforums but can subforums have further subforums? You have not included the structure of your forums table. Does the forum hierarchy follow the same hierarchy as categories?

Comment: Sorry, I realized my question was badly described, using Cats & Prods instead of Forums & Topics. I edited it to match my description. My brain really was mush at the time of the orig post.

I only want to have 2 levels, a top level (which can contain topics), and a lower level, a child of a top level. I don't need any more complexity :)

Comment: I have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to lack of clarity in your question I have had to make some assumptions but you should be able to modify this to fit your table/field names. I have included a filter based on date in the innermost query to try to reduce the overhead. You may need to modify the `topics.date_added > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` criterion to make sure you will always have 3 entries per forum group -

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        tmp.*,
        @rank := IF(@forum=forum_id, @rank + 1, 1) rank, 
        @forum := forum_id
    FROM (
        SELECT
            forums.id AS forum_id,
            forums.name AS forum_name,
            NULL AS subforum_id,
            NULL AS subforum_name,
            topics.name AS topic_name,
            topics.date_added
        FROM forums
        INNER JOIN topics
            ON (forums.id = topics.forum_id)
        WHERE topics.date_added > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND forums.parent_id = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            forums.id AS forum_id,
            forums.name AS forum_name,
            subforums.id AS subforum_id,
            subforums.id AS subforum_name,
            topics.name AS topic_name,
            topics.date_added
        FROM forums
        INNER JOIN forums subforums
            ON forums.id = subforums.parent_id
        INNER JOIN topics
            ON subforums.id = topics.forum_id
        WHERE topics.date_added > (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND forums.parent_id = 0
        ORDER BY forum_id ASC, date_added DESC
    ) tmp, (SELECT @forum:=NULL, @rank:=NULL) initvars
) tmp2
WHERE rank <= 3
```

Note: I have not tried this so there may be syntax errors.

Comment: **HOLY $#!+** it works! **thank you _nnichols__!** At first I was so intimidated by the size of that query, I was about to give up my dream. I got some good sleep, and attacked it the next day, walking through the whole query, learning what each part did. I have learned some fishing (not just copy & pasting)

Comment: I am glad it has solved your problem and that you have learnt from it. So many people expect on answer and don't care to understand it properly. Good on you!

Comment: I am working on documenting the query, describing every step that it does, and then I will post it here on SO, so others reading it will learn. thanks again for your help. it looks like you got the credit, correct? do you have a personal blog?